# Historical Prices via FinancialData

Tags: data

I downloaded the historical stock prices for some stocks in the period 1990-2013 via FinancialData some months ago and computed the financial returns.
Now I downloaded the data again for the same stocks in the same period but obtain slightly diffrent returns.

Why is this so? I use the same code. These are the historical prices, they should not change. Are the prices being adjusted every couple of moths somehow?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Ana! Please post your code. Also, a good start to identifying the problem would be to identify where the changes were. Did you keep the input values you previously got from `FinancialData`.

Comment: Stock quotes are obtained from Yahoo finance, so any differences are probably caused there.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think I have the answer now, Mathematica uses the adjusted prices from Yahoo finance, that means the prices corrected by dividends and splits, this leads to adjustment in the historical prices every time there are splits or dividends are paid out.